# JQuery draw line on canvas image and reset line without affecting image

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas

I have this problem where I upload an image from an input field and draw it into a canvas. I have event listeners (`mousemove`, `click`, `keydown`), where when the user clicks on any part of the image, that point is the `x1`, `y1` coordinates, and when they move the mouse, that's where the `x2`, `y2` is updated each time.

The problem is that there always needs to be one line, which I manage with a function named `resetLine`, so when the `x2`, `y2` change, the line is reset so we don't end up with a bunch of continuous lines with each mouse move.

The issue is with the image we are drawing on, the way I am resetting the lines also seems to reset the image, which I think is expected, so I have to redraw the image on every mouse move which I believe is not the right way to do this, and also you could see the image flickering everytime you move the mouse.
Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: here is an example I made earlier, but the image is made into css background url image using javascript, but it had many issues that I had to start drawing the background image using canvas:
https://angle-measurement.herokuapp.com

and here is a similar one I made on codepen:
https://codepen.io/Overflow0x/pen/yLaZxqm, but they all use css's background-image, instead of canvas.

```js
class APP {
  constructor() {
    this.$imageFileInput = $("#imageFileInput");
    this.$lineWeight = $("#lineWeight");
    this.$lineColor = $("#lineColor");
    this.$reset = $("#reset");
    this.$canvas = $("#canvas");
    this.canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    this.lineColor = "";
    this.lineWidth = 3;
    
    this.x1y1 = {
      x: 4,
      y: 8
    };
    
    this.x2y2 = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    };
    
    this.imageDataUrl = null;
    this.imageWidth = 0;
    this.imageHeight = 0;
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.y2X2MoveHandlerState = 0;
    // 0 unregistered, 1, registered
  }

  setCanvasDimentions() {
    this.ctx.canvas.width = (83 / 100) * window.innerWidth;
    this.ctx.canvas.height = (60 / 100) * window.innerHeight;
  }

  registerX1Y1ClickHandler() {
    var self = this;
    self.$canvas.on('click', function(event) {
      //console.log('registerX1Y2ClickHandler event\t', event);
      console.log("click", event)
      self.x1y1 = self.getMousePos(event);
      self.log();
    });
  }

  registerSaveLineClickHandler() {
    var self = this;
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
      console.warn(e);
      if (e.keyCode == 83) {
        // 's' button pressed...
        self.toggleY2X2MoveHandler();
      }
    });
  }

  registerY2X2MoveHandler(mode = null) {
    this.y2X2MoveHandlerState = 1;
    var self = this;
    self.$canvas.on('mousemove', function(event) {
      console.log("mousemove", event);
      self.x2y2 = self.getMousePos(event);
      self.log();
      self.resetLine();
      self.draw_line();
      self.draw_angle();
    });
  }

  toggleY2X2MoveHandler() {
    var self = this;
    if (self.y2X2MoveHandlerState == 0) {
      self.registerY2X2MoveHandler();
    } else {
      self.$canvas.off("mousemove");
      self.y2X2MoveHandlerState = 0;
    }
  }

  registerOnImageChangeHandler() {
    var self = this;
    self.$imageFileInput.on('change', function(event) {
      console.log("image change", event);
      const file = event.target.files[0];
      self.getBase64Promise(file).then(function(result) {
        self.imageDataUrl = result;
        self.drawImage(result);
        //self.ctx.canvas.style.backgroundImage = 'url(\'' + result + '\')';
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.error("ikh\t", error)
        self.error = error;
      })
    });
  }

  registerOnLineWeightChangeHandler() {
    var self = this;
    self.$lineWeight.on('change', function(event) {
      self.lineWidth = event.target.value;
    });
  }

  registerOnColorChangeHandler() {
    var self = this;
    self.$lineColor.on('change', function(event) {
      self.lineColor = event.target.value;
    });
  }

  registerOnResetHandler() {
    var self = this;
    self.$reset.on('click', function() {
      var cords = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
      };
      self.x1y1 = cords;
      self.x2y2 = cords;
      self.resetLine();
    });
  }

  angle() {
    var x1y1 = this.getObjectValuesAsArray(this.x1y1);
    var x2y2 = this.getObjectValuesAsArray(this.x2y2);
    var x1 = x1y1[0]
    var y1 = x1y1[1]
    var x2 = x2y2[0]
    var y2 = x2y2[1]
    var dy = y2 - y1;
    var dx = x2 - x1;
    var theta = Math.atan2(dy, dx); // range (-PI, PI]
    theta *= 180 / Math.PI; // rads to degs, range (-180, 180]
    //if (theta < 0) theta = 360 + theta; // range [0, 360)
    theta = Number(theta).toPrecision(4);
    return theta;
  }

  getBase64Promise(file) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = function() {
        return resolve(reader.result);
      };
      reader.onerror = function(error) {
        return reject(error);
      };
    });
  }

  getMousePos(event) {
    var rect = this.$canvas.get(0).getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
      x: (event.clientX - rect.left) / (rect.right - rect.left) * this.ctx.canvas.width,
      y: (event.clientY - rect.top) / (rect.bottom - rect.top) * this.ctx.canvas.height
    };
  }

  /*
  This code (getMousePos) takes into account both changing coordinates to canvas space 
  (evt.clientX - rect.left) and scaling when canvas logical size differs 
  from its style size 
  (/ (rect.right - rect.left) * canvas.width see: Canvas width and height in HTML5).
  */

  getObjectValuesAsArray(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).map(function(k) {
      return obj[k]
    });
  }

  resetLine() {
    this.ctx.save();
    this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'copy';
    this.ctx.strokeStyle = 'transparent';
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.lineTo(0, 0);
    this.ctx.stroke();
    this.drawImage(this.imageDataUrl);
    this.ctx.restore();
  }

  drawImage(result) {
    var self = this;
    console.warn(result);
    var img = $('<img>', {
      src: result
    });
    img.on('load', function() {
      console.warn("jq image\t", img);
      self.imageWidth = img.get(0).naturalWidth;
      self.imageHeight = img.get(0).naturalHeight;
      self.ctx.canvas.width = img.get(0).naturalWidth;
      self.ctx.canvas.height = img.get(0).naturalHeight;
      self.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, self.ctx.canvas.width, self.ctx.canvas.height);
      self.ctx.drawImage(img.get(0), 0, 0, self.ctx.canvas.width, self.ctx.canvas.height);
    });
  }

  draw_line() {
    this.ctx.strokeStyle = this.lineColor;
    this.ctx.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;
    var x1y1 = this.getObjectValuesAsArray(this.x1y1);
    var x2y2 = this.getObjectValuesAsArray(this.x2y2);
    //console.log("vectors x1y1\t", x1y1, "\t vectors x2y2", x2y2);
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.moveTo(x1y1[0], x1y1[1]);
    this.ctx.lineTo(x2y2[0], x2y2[1]);
    this.ctx.stroke();
    //this.ctx.strokeRect(vectors[0], vectors[1], vectors[2], vectors[3]);
  }

  draw_angle() {
    this.ctx.strokeStyle = this.lineColor;
    this.ctx.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;
    var x2y2 = this.getObjectValuesAsArray(this.x2y2);
    //console.log("vectors x1y1\t", x1y1, "\t vectors x2y2", x2y2);
    this.ctx.font = "18px DejaVuSansMono33-Regular";
    this.ctx.fillStyle = this.lineColor;
    var x2 = x2y2[0];
    var y2 = x2y2[1];
    var dx = x2;
    var dy = y2;
    var width = this.ctx.canvas.width;
    var height = this.ctx.canvas.height;

    console.warn("canvas width and height", width, height);


    this.ctx.fillText(this.angle() + "°", dx, dy);
    //this.ctx.strokeRect(vectors[0], vectors[1], vectors[2], vectors[3]);
  }

  log() {
    console.log("x2y2\t", this.x2y2);
    //console.log("ctx", this.ctx)
  }

  init() {
    this.setCanvasDimentions();
    this.registerX1Y1ClickHandler();
    this.registerY2X2MoveHandler();
    this.registerOnImageChangeHandler();
    this.registerOnColorChangeHandler();
    this.registerOnLineWeightChangeHandler();
    this.registerSaveLineClickHandler();
    this.registerOnResetHandler();
    this.log();
  }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  var app = new APP();
  app.init();
});
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'DejaVuSansMono33-Regular';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: url("/static/DejaVuSansMono33-Regular.otf") format("truetype");
}

html,
body {
  font-family: DejaVuSansMono33-Regular, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  background: "red";
  height: 100%;
}

canvas#canvas {
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  display: inline;
}

#measure {
  position: absolute;
  left: -10000px;
  top: -100000px;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  background: #f2f6f8;
}

#canvas-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: none;
}

input[type="color"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}

input[type="color"]::-webkit-color-swatch-wrapper {
  padding: 0;
}

input[type="color"]::-webkit-color-swatch {
  border: none;
}

.container {
  height: 100% !important;
}

.section {
  padding-bottom: 0px !important;
  margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.1/css/bulma.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <section class="section">
    <div class="columns">
      <div class="column">
        <div class="container">
          <div id="canvas-container">
            <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
            <div id="measure"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="section" style="padding-top: 10rem;">
    <div class="columns">
      <div class="column">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="field is-horizontal">
            <div class="field-body">
              <div class="field">
                <div class="file is-dark">
                  <label class="file-label">
                    <input class="file-input" type="file" name="imageFileInput" id="imageFileInput">
                    <span class="file-cta">
                      <span class="file-label">Upload Picture</span>
                    </span>
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="field">
                <button class="button is-dark" id="reset">Reset to initial coordinates</button>
              </div>
              <div class="field">
                <label class="label is-expanded">Vector Color</label>
                <div class="control">
                  <input class="input" type="color" name="lineColor" id="lineColor" value="#000000" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="field">
                <label class="label">Vector Size</label>
                <div class="control">
                  <input class="input" type="number" name="lineWeight" id="lineWeight" min="0" value="2" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is clearly this function:

```
  drawImage(result) {
    var self = this;
    console.warn(result);
    var img = $('<img>', {
      src: result
    });
    img.on('load', function() {
      console.warn("jq image\t", img);
      self.imageWidth = img.get(0).naturalWidth;
      self.imageHeight = img.get(0).naturalHeight;
      self.ctx.canvas.width = img.get(0).naturalWidth;
      self.ctx.canvas.height = img.get(0).naturalHeight;
      self.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, self.ctx.canvas.width, self.ctx.canvas.height);
      self.ctx.drawImage(img.get(0), 0, 0, self.ctx.canvas.width, self.ctx.canvas.height);
    });
  }
```

but what is actually happening there?

Well, beside `resetLine()` and `draw_angle()` it's part of your mouseMove callback handler and thus gets executed with every mouse movement.

So with:

```
    var img = $('<img>', {
      src: result
    });
```

you're creating a new image and with:

```
img.on('load', function() {});
```

you're actually waiting for it to be 'loaded' - with **every** mouse movement.

That means the flickering you observe is caused by the time it takes until the onload event for the image is fired and your canvas finally gets an image to draw.

The fix is rather simple. I'd recommend setting up a class variable e.g.

`this.image=null;`

and modify the drawImage() function in the following way:

- if `this.image` is **null**, add the onLoad listener and assign the local variable `img` to `this.image`
- if `this.image` is **not** null, use it as a reference instead of `img`

Something like:

```
  drawImage(result) {
    var self = this;
    console.warn(result);
    var img = $('<img>', {
      src: result
    });

    if (this.image == null) {
      img.on('load', function() {
        console.warn("jq image\t", img);
        self.imageWidth = img.get(0).naturalWidth;
        self.imageHeight = img.get(0).naturalHeight;
        self.ctx.canvas.width = img.get(0).naturalWidth;
        self.ctx.canvas.height = img.get(0).naturalHeight;
        self.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, self.ctx.canvas.width, self.ctx.canvas.height);
        self.ctx.drawImage(img.get(0), 0, 0, self.ctx.canvas.width, self.ctx.canvas.height);
      });
      this.image = img;
    } else {
      img = this.image;
      self.imageWidth = img.get(0).naturalWidth;
      self.imageHeight = img.get(0).naturalHeight;
      self.ctx.canvas.width = img.get(0).naturalWidth;
      self.ctx.canvas.height = img.get(0).naturalHeight;
      self.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, self.ctx.canvas.width, self.ctx.canvas.height);
      self.ctx.drawImage(img.get(0), 0, 0, self.ctx.canvas.width, self.ctx.canvas.height);
    }
  }
```

Just as a side note - this is by no means the most elegant way to do this, it's just meant to get you started.

Comment: thank you for your time and help, I understood your explanation, but now, I get the same image even if I upload a new one, and this same image disappears on the first mouse move event, any ideas, please?

Comment: No problem Murphy! The problem is that `image` doesn't ever get 'reset' to null again, true. You can do this right inside the fileInput change event callback  self.$imageFileInput.on('change', function(event) {
      console.log("image change", event);
  self.image=null;
  // remaining code
    });

Comment: Thank you, you are correct. I don't wanna be a bother, but why do you think the image disappears after a mouse move? is it perhaps because of the way I am handling the resetLine(), or drawAngle() as you mentioned them in your answer?